# I'm getting an error using Figaro gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The error messages references a line in the gem, but I'm suspecting my trouble lay in my `.yml` file, which is here (with phony ids)

```
S3_KEY:ANGELINAANGELINA 

S3_SECRET:becaUSEILIKEherthatiswhy

S3_BUCKET:nameofmybucket
```

/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:39:in `flatten': undefined method`reject' for # (`NoMethodError`)

Comment: Parsing error, Maybe need a space after the :

Comment: have a space after each :

Comment: Right you are, gentlemen. Thanks very much. The spacer did it. I don't know how to put up the green checkmark(!)

Answer (score 4):

Well if you're just handing out green checks... I'll take one! :)

Parsing error, have a space after each :

Answer (score 1):

Figaro doesn't parse tab space either. That means that if you want any indentation, you will need to use single spaces. You can use an online parser to validate your code and play around. Here's one: http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: It was tabs for me

Answer (score 1):

S3_KEY: ANGELINAANGELINA

S3_SECRET: becaUSEILIKEherthatiswhy

S3_BUCKET: nameofmybucket

Terminal : figaro install,
To create the yml file and use the above format

Comment: Inserting a space after the `:` is sufficient. The quotes aren't necessary. See the comment by the questioner below. Also, I verified that quotes aren't necessary in a YAML parser.